# AttributeError with Py-StackExchange

Tags: support, api-v2, python

i'm trying to execute this python script :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import stackexchange
so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)

my_favourite_guy = so.user(41981)
print my_favourite_guy.reputation.format()
print len(my_favourite_guy.answers), 'answers'
```

But i got this error

```
Jarvis:Documents Adeel$ python stackexchange.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackexchange.py", line 3, in <module>
    import stackexchange
  File "/Users/Adeel/Documents/stackexchange.py", line 5, in <module>
    so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Site'
```

It works fine when I copy and paste it on the python shell :

```
Jarvis:~ Adeel$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stackexchange
>>> so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)
>>> my_favourite_guy = so.user(41981)
>>> print my_favourite_guy.reputation.format()
11.2k
>>> print len(my_favourite_guy.answers), 'answers'
239 answers
```

I don't understand why..can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is named `stackexchange.py`, so Python is recursively loading it instead. This is a very common Python pitfall:

- [Stack Overflow: *python 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9149876/1053021)
- [Someone's badly formatted code with the same problem](http://python.questionfor.info/q_python_7947.html)
- Django tickets {[1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13872#comment:2), [2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/rI7fHSjI7FQ/3KKodbGhdSIJ)}
- [Again on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947236)
- [New module causes interesting conflicts](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpickle/issues/detail?id=4)
- [And here it is again on linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/python-attributeerror-%27module%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27main%27-4175478873/)

## Fix

Change the filename: call your script `se-test.py` or something.